# How to display image and its corresponding text

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting data as json through jquery and after parsing it I am getting some images and corresponding to these images some text. My problem is I want to display on my web page like this.
"some image" : corresponding text.

How can I do this.

The problem is here:

```
$.each(result.response.docs, function(i,item){
            src1=item.image;

            html+="<p><br>"+"<img src="+src1+  " />";
            html += "   UID_PK: ="+ item.UID_PK;
            html += "<br>Name: ="+ item.name;
            html += "<br>Description: ="+ item.description;
            html += "<br>Price: ="+ item.price;
            // ("#result").html(html);

            // alt1="No Image"
            //image+="<br>IMAGE: "+"<img src="+src1+ " alt="+alt1+ " />";
            //image+="<br>"+"<img src="+src1+ " />";
})
$("#result").html(html);
```

where result is a . I wanted to ask should I make separate div for both image and text. And if I do this then I'll have to call `$("#result").html(html); ("#image").html(image);` in side the loop. And what if I do not have images for some text, then I want to make that space blank.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @bjoernz: I have edited my question, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is display your JSON image and text from javascript!
Here's a **crude** solution:

```
var imgAndText = "<img src='"+jsonObject.imgSrc+"' />"; 
imgAndText += "<br/>";
imgAndText += "<p>"+jsonObject.imgText+"</p>";

document.write(imgAndText);
```

This constructs the html and displays it on the page!

**EDIT**

if there is no image:

```
var imagAndText;

if(jsonObject.imgSrc != null && jsonObject.imgSrc != "") {
    imgAndText = "<img src='"+jsonObject.imgSrc+"' />"; 
} else {
    imgAndText = "<img src='defaultImg.jpg' />"; 
}

imgAndText += "<br/>";
imgAndText += "<p>"+jsonObject.imgText+"</p>";

document.write(imgAndText);
```

This should check to see if there is an imgSrc in the jsonObject...if there is, use it else use a predefined image which could be blank or anything you want.

**EDIT 2**

Just clarifying from @Anze below...

change the else closure to :

```
else {
    imgAndText = "<div class="image_placeholder"></div>"; 
}
```

in your css:

```
.image_placeholder {
 width:150px; /*your default width*/
 height:150px;  /*your default height*/
}
```

Comment: for some text there is no image but i want to make space for that image then what can i do for this

Comment: i am not allowed to put some default image, can i do this using <div>, but how i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgAndText = '';

if(jsonObject.imgSrc != null || jsonObject.imgSrc != "") {
    imgAndText += "<img src='"+jsonObject.imgSrc+"' alt='"+jsonObject.imgText+"' />"; 
} else {
    imgAndText += "<div class='image_placeholder'></div>"; 
}

imgAndText += "<br/>";
imgAndText += "<p>"+jsonObject.imgText+"</p>";

document.write(imgAndText);
```